# ImageMagick conversion with PSD file

Tags: java, image, imagemagick

We are using Imagemagick with Version: ImageMagick 7.0.8-7. We are running the same in Linux environment.

We used the following command to generate the thumbnail.

```
convert src.psd -intent relative -density 72 -sample “500x375>” - 
quality 80 -colorspace sRGB -strip -auto-orient dest.jpg
```

The thumbnail generation works fine. I am able to open the file and check the thumbnail. The problem is that the generated thumbnail is not opening in browser.

When I went a deeper, I found that the following are the properties of the generated thumbnail image. (used EXIFTOOL)

```
File Type                       : PSD
File Type Extension             : psd
MIME Type                       : application/vnd.adobe.photoshop
```

I think the mimetype and file extensions are preventing it from rendering in the browser.

Any help or directions to solve this problem will be appreciated.!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following ImageMagick command

```
magick src.psd[0] -auto-orient -strip -colorspace sRGB -density 72 -sample “500x375>” -quality 80 dest.jpg
```

Use [0] to convert only the flattened layer.

Do you have libjpeg installed?

What do you get from

```
magick -version
```

Does that list JPG?

Can you post a link to your PDF file?  My tests on my Mac with IM 7.0.8.7 seem to work fine with just

```
magick image.pdf[0] image.jpg
```

EXIFTOOL shows JPG